# Converting a String constructor in a class into a button in another class

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to make changes in the "Student" class to (I guess) convert it from a string to a button. For instance, I need to be able to call the student class and create a new operator(?) and add it to a JPanel as a button.

Normally it would look like this:

`Student st1 = new student("Random","Name", 44);`

What I need to be able to do is call the student class and produce something like:

`st1.setText("Random");`
`add(st1)`

I'm not sure what changes to make in the student class. I thought maybe I could use the `compareTo` operator to produce the desired results but haven't had much luck and the tutorials I've found on the subject don't help much.

My student class looks like this:

```
public class student {
  // Tried calling a JButton to send to the JPanel class which didn't work
  // Also tried to create a method which would convert a string to a JButton, but still couldn't send to JPanel

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int age;

  public student(String a, String b, int x) // Tried calling a JButton as a constructor which didn't work
  {
    super();
    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
    age = x;
  }

  String getInfo() {
    return "NAME = " + firstName + "  " + lastName + "  " + "Age = " + age;
  }

  String whatsUp() {
    double r = Math.random();
    int myNumber = (int) (r * 3f); //comment: a random number between 0 and 2
    String answer = "I don't know";
    if (myNumber == 0) {
      answer = "searching the web";
    }
    if (myNumber == 1) {
      answer = "doing Java";
    }
    if (myNumber == 2) {
      answer = "Listening to endless lecture";
    }
    return answer;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to write setter?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, and I'm not sure where to start. All I know is that I should be able to call this: student st1 = new student("fred","fonseca", 22);
    add(st1);
    st1.setBackgound(Color.blue); From JPanel and make the necessary changes in student to make that happen

Comment: What `add` method should do and where it should be defined? and what `setBackground` method should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a stylistic note, your classes should be capitalized so that they are easily distinguishable from your methods. The [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28java.lang.String%29) constructor takes a String, Icon, or Action. Make your Student class a subclass of JButton.

```
public class Student extends JButton {
    ...
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        return super(firstName + lastName + Integer.toString(age));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get that, but the assignment states that I have to be able to create a JButton from the student class. In other words, the "student" has to BE the button.

Comment: Your Student class should extend JButton.